# Piano Keys/ Audio Files do not run

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I am trying to build a basic piano that plays a sound when you click on the key of the piano. I am using HTML, CSS and Javascript and when I click on the piano keys, it does not respond and there is no sound. I have checked the path way for the audio and const in my JS code but cannot figure anything out...Can someone explain whats wrong with the code?

```
HTML CODE: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="magicPiano.css">
    <script src="magicPiano.js" defer></script>
    <title>Magic Piano</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="piano">
        <div data-note="C" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-note="D" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="E" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-note="Eb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="F" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="Gb" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-note="G" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="Ab" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-note="A" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-note="Bb" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-note="B" class="key white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="audio"></div>
    <audio id="C" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_C.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Db" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Db.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="D" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_D.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="E" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_E.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Eb" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Eb.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="F" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_F.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Gb" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Gb.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="G" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Gb.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Ab" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Ab.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="A" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_A.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Bb" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_Bb.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="B" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_B.mp3"></audio>


</body>

</html>
```

```
CSS CODE:

*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.piano{
    display: flex;

}

.key {
height: calc(var(--width) * 4);
width: var(--width);
}

.white{
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.black{
    width: 60px;
    height: 240px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    z-index: 2;

}
```

```
JS CODE:

const white_keys = ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm']
const black_keys = ['s', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'j']

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key')

const whiteKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.key.white')
const blackKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.key.black')

keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener('click', () => playNote(key))
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', @ => {
    if (e.repeat) return
    const key = e.key
    const whiteKeyIndex = white_keys.indexOf(key)
    const blackKeyIndex = black_keys.indexOf(key)

    if (whiteKeyIndex > -1) playNote(whiteKeys[whiteKeyIndex])
    if (blackKeyIndex > -1) playNote(blackKeys[blackKeyIndex])

})

function playNote(key) {
    const noteAudio = (document.getElementById(key.dataset.note));
    noteAudio.currentTime = 0
    noteAudio.play()
    key.classList.add('active')
    noteAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        key.classList.remove('active')

    })
```

Comment: Hi Jessie, this is just a guess at the moment but it could be because you have spaces in the path names for your audio files. Lilke this... `<audio id="B" src="/Users/admin/Projects/Magic Piano/notes_B.mp3"></audio>`. Try renaming the 'Magic Piano' folder to 'magicpiano'. That might work but I am unsure at the moment. Generally speaking try not to use spaces in your path names.

Comment: `'keydown', @ =>` should be `'keydown', () =>` and you you miss a `}` at the end of your file.